# Join gives warning "file1 is not in sorted order"

Tags: bash, unix

Was testing a legacy script in the new version of bash 4.1.2(1)-release
, and encountered this warning in the console:

```
join: file 1 is not in sorted order
join: file 2 is not in sorted order
```

I am quite sure that both of the files are sorted. The files actually merged properly.

Below is the script:

```
cat $FILE1_PATH'.processed.1' | cut -d'|' -f4,8 | sort | uniq -u  > $FILE1_PATH.'processed.2'
cat $FILE2_PATH'.processed.1' | cut -d'|' -f1,8 | sort | uniq -u > $FILE2_PATH.'processed.2'
join -t$'|' -1 1 -2 1 $FILE1_PATH.'processed.2' $FILE2_PATH.'processed.2' > $MERGEFILE_PATH
```

To job of this script :

1. extract field 4 and 8 from file 1
2. extract field 1 and 8 from file 2
3. combine the extracted fields, using join key file1.field4 = file2.field1
4. remove any duplicates.

FILE1.processed.2 :

```
21VIANET GP INC|GOV
ABN|ABN1
ABN|ABN2
ABOC|ABOC1
ABOC|ABOC1
ABOC|ABOC2
....
```

FILE2.processed.2 :

```
ABN|Banks
ABOC|Pharmaceuticals
GOV|Government Agency 
....
```

OUTPUT:

```
GOV|21VIANET GP INC|Government Agency
ABN|ABN1|Banks
ABN|ABN2|Banks
ABOC|ABOC1|Pharmaceuticals
ABOC|ABOC2|Pharmaceuticals  
....
```

Running the same script in the bash version 3.2.25(1)-release gives no warning. Any idea to solve the warning?

UPDATE:
Seems that the cause was caused by these lines in the input files...

```
ADBC|Banks 
ADB|Banks
```

Join expects ADBC to be positioned after ADB, like below :

```
ADB|Banks
ADBC|Banks
```

However I tried to change my sort script from sort -u to sort -t$'|' -k1 (sort based on the first field ) however still not working...

Comment: At first glance, I'm not sure but that cat cut awk sort combo could probably be simplified tremendously!

Comment: It would be useful if you indicated exactly what you're trying to do, showing your desired output. I suspect that it could probably be achieved in a single awk statement, which would solve your problem (albeit indirectly).

Comment: Your naming scheme is slightly confusing but if I understand correctly, the files that you have shown are the ones that you are passing to `join`. What does `FILE1.processed.1` look like? It may be easier to go from the input straight to the output.

Comment: I noticed that the awk is not necessary, since the field will be rearranged again later. I have also updated the question to include what the script supposed to do and desired output.

Comment: If the error message is reported by the join command, what does that have to be with "bash"? Have you run the same script with bash 3.2.25 either in other box or in the same box? Different OS releases usually contains different releases of join command, not only different bash releases

Comment: This is most likely a locale issue. Try settimg LC_COLLATE explicitly to C so that sort and join are both using the same collation order

Comment: You might change the `sort | uniq -u` to just `sort -u`.  I don't know if that will fix the problem, but I'd be concerned that uniq is doing something funny.  Beyond that, I like @rici's hypothesis for the problem.  I also share @TomFenech's question about the original input files and going straight from input to output.

Comment: After testing, found the issue caused by sort... adding "UPDATE" in the question

Comment: Use `-k1,1` otherwise you're not really sorting on field 1 alone

Comment: Also `$'|'` works, but it's weird-looking. You've probably seen examples like `sort -t $'\t'` and you're copying it without realizing that the reason they used it was that the `$'...'` construct provides escapes (like `\t` for tab). When you just want a pipe character in your command, `'|'` will do.

Comment: Wumpus, you are right, would like to approve your answer. Please put answer below. need to add -k1,1 :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The suggestion in the `join` man page is to use `sort -k 1b,1` when you're joining on field 1. (It says "when join has no options" but as far as field selection is concerned, your join is equivalent to no options. `-1 1` and `-2 1` are the defaults.) You can add `-t '|'` to that and it will match your `join` perfectly.

`-k1` means all fields from 1 to the end. `-k1,1` means just field 1. The `b` is necessary if you have leading whitespace and want to ignore it. sort syntax is weird. And this is *after* POSIX redesigned it to try to make it sensible. If you ever write a sort command that doesn't look complicated, it's probably not doing what you wanted.

Add `--debug` to your sort command to see what it's using as a key. With a sample file containing these lines:

```
ADBC|Banks
ADB|Banks
 ADBC|Banks
```

you can see the effect of various `-k` options:

```
$ sort -s -t '|' -k 1 --debug file
sort: using simple byte comparison
 ADBC|Banks
___________
ADBC|Banks
__________
ADB|Banks
_________
$ sort -s -t '|' -k 1,1 --debug file
sort: using simple byte comparison
 ADBC|Banks
_____
ADB|Banks
___
ADBC|Banks
____
$ sort -s -t '|' -k 1b,1 --debug file
sort: using simple byte comparison
ADB|Banks
___
ADBC|Banks
____
 ADBC|Banks
 ____
```

Now you're probably wondering about the `-s` I threw in there. Without it, there is a default last-resort comparison of the whole line as a string, which applies to lines with equal keys. That's not normally a problem and you probably don't need to use `-s`. It's just that when using `--debug`, the last-resort comparison clutters the list so I like to use `-s` to get rid of it.